# EC2 instance has apache2 server installed, but I can't connect to it

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 18.04, with apache2 server.
I am able to connect to it via PuTTY and via FileZilla and view the server. 
The server is running, there is the `index.html` file that's created by apache2 under `/var/www`, but still when I type in my public IPv4 address in the browser, I cannot connect and view the apache2 welcome page (Cannot connect to it)

What may be the cause? Is it possible that it's because I am on free tier and I am already running another EC2 instance? (Which is working fine)

*Edit: I ran the following commands and these are the outputs:

```
netstat -plunt | grep "443 \|80 "
```

> (Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info  will
>   not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.) tcp6       0
>   0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN

```
curl -I http://localhost
```

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Mon, 31 Dec 2018 16:39:42 GMT Server:
>   Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Last-Modified: Mon, 31 Dec 2018 12:54:24 GMT
>   ETag: "2bb4-56f5oe88329x4" Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 10918
>   Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Type: text/html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want to expose a service/port on an EC2 Instance, you need to create a security group which allows connections in that port and attach it to the instance.

So for example, you can create a security group like so:
[image]

And when you attach it to the instance, it will allow connections on port 80 from all the world (0.0.0.0/0).

Also, I'd check that the server actually listens on this port, run:

```
netstat -plunt | grep "443 \|80 "
```

And to see that the server responds:

```
curl -I http://localhost
```

Comment: The server responds, and I already have a running EC2 instance on the same VPC, so there is already a security group that allows traffic from all IPs (The other instance is working fine and I can get to the website it's running in the browser)

Comment: I edited the post and added the commands output

Comment: If you run the curl command from outside of the server, which http status code is returned?

Comment: What do you mean outside of the server? where?

Comment: You say that you can't reach the server from the browser, so I mean, instead of trying to reach the server by browser, run the curl command, just not from the server itself. I want to see how the server responds when you try to access it from the world (0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: But where do I type this command then? I am on Windows

Comment: https://onlinecurl.com/

Comment: I found out the problem: Although in the security groups I already had rules that allow for inbound traffic from all IPs, they were not attached to my specific EC2 instance, but to the other EC2 instance, so each instance has it's own security group called something like `launch-wizard-x` and I needed to edit the correct. confusing

Comment: You can assign any security group to any EC2 instance.

Comment: This worked for me - by default the exposed port in security group is 22 - you need to add HTTP/TCP/80.

Comment: Exactly this issue I had to fix on my EC2 instance. the port 80 is not exposed by default.

Comment: Thanks for saving my time. :D

Answer (score 5):

Try http, not the default https. This finally worked for me.

Comment: Yes! Even though you got downvoted, this was my issue... The link in the EC2 instance page goes to 'https://' but the default apache install only listens to http, causing the browser to say "no worky"

Comment: It worked for me as well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Such a minor detail missed. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "https://64.198.24.123" is the default and what was automatically opened on the browser, but when I removed the 's' from it: "http://64.198.24.123", it works.